# Paperback ID: Alien invasion; Black Discs vs. White Discs in London

Tags: story-identification, aliens

The story concerned some alien invasion.  The final "scenes" took place in London, I think.

There were two kinds of aliens invading, using different colored disc-shaped ships.  The bad aliens were black and the good aliens were white. 
 I think the last bit was the surviving humans waiting to see which colour, black or white, the approaching ship was.  It was the good aliens.  End of book.

I read this in paperback in the sixties.